# Blender 2.83.5 will not run if archive extracted with xarchive

Tags: linux

If you extract the archive file blender-2.83.5-linux64.tar.xz with xarchiver
you may get all of the files extracted into one directory. This obviously
won't work, blender fails to start, generating several missing file errors,
since the directory structure that it expects is missing

Comment: sounds like a bug in xarchiver, possibly raise it with them? https://github.com/ib/xarchiver/issues/

Comment: Is there supposed to be a question in this question?

Answer (score 2):

Yikes! Forgot to answer how I fixed this. Extract with
tar --xz -xfv

Sorry!